# Finding the largest value in a 2-dimensional range and returning the column header

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, range, lookup

I've been struggling to find a solution to locating the maximal number within a 2-dimensional range and then  looking up the column header that the maximal number falls into.

For example:
[image: example table]

I'm looking for a formula that would lookup the maximal number in the range **A2** to **C5** (in this example `9669`). Then lookup the column that that number falls into (in this example **Person C**), and then return that value.

Seems simply enough for a 1-dimensional range, but I can't find anything for dealing with 2-dimensions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I am glad that you like the new formatting. Just a note: Questions of type "please do this for me" are not welcome here. You should show some effort - for example what did you try already and which problems did you encounter. --- One more note :) thanks for answers are expressed by accepting the answer and upvotes. It is not necessary to thank in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Microsoft itself states: [*"So, you want to become a real Excel power user? In that case, you need to know how to use array formulas"*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx).

The solution consists of three steps:

1. define a matrix that searches for the maximum value's,
2. transform that matrix to 1's and 0's,
3. multiply that matrix with a vector containing the column numbers.

*Step 1:* As an experiment, try to select a range equal to your table size, and your enter `=<table range> = MAX(<table range>)` and you confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> (the default key for entering array formulas).

*Step 2:* The double minus operator converts the `TRUE`/`FALSE` values to 0's (for FALSE) and 1's (for TRUE).

*Step 3:* Use `SUMPRODUCT` and `COLUMN` to multiply the array and to create the vector with column numbers.

So your formula looks like: `SUMPRODUCT(--( <table range> = MAX( <table range> )) * COLUMN( <table range> ))` (of course, replace `<table range>` with the range or name of your table.

Note that this formula returns the *absolute* worksheet column number of the found maximum value. So, 5 for column E in your worksheet. If you want the *relative* number in your table, subtract by the column of the left-top cell of your table and add one. So your formula becomes: `SUMPRODUCT(--( <table range> =MAX( <table range> )) * COLUMN( <table range> )) - COLUMN( <left top cell of table> ) + 1`

Also note that this final formula uses array formula's, but is in itself not an array, but a single value. So to enter this formula, you can just click <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

My working example:
[image: Using SUMPRODUCT to get the column number of the maximum value in an Excel array]

Answer (score 0):

Very nice answer and nice mention of the `--` concept.

However, the `--` is unnecessary as ANY multiplication (or addition, etc.) on the {TRUE/FALSE} array produced by the equality test will change its contents from {TRUE/FALSE} to {1/0}. So multiplying by the column number will take care of that without resort to `--`.

Also, nitpicking now, `SUM()` will work just fine instead of `SUMPRODUCT()`. There is only one item to operate on so no array "product" aspect, really. It's not being used in its "natural form" anyhow (TWO operands, not the one), rather it is just a beard wrapped around the inner workings that makes sense out of the result from the inner workings. `SUM()` can do that nicely, is easier to type, and  not "scary looking."

Nice use of `COLUMN()`. To generalize it, so as to make it expand or contract if the range is pushed right or left by column insertion or deletion, one might use `(COLUMN(B2:D4)-COLUMNS($A2:B4)-1)`.

Finally, using the above in an `HLOOKUP()` of the column header row would find the asked for information.

If one does the last, as asked for, the column calculation just above it can be simplified to `COLUMN(B2:D4)` if one does the `HLOOKUP()` using, in this case, A2:D2 as the lookup range, rather than the naturally desired B2:D2. Doing that means there's no need to make the above adjustment, so... much easier.